# How to get the particular column value of the EXEC result in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm executing a query like

```
EXEC [dbo].[GET_ALL_RECORDS] @ProjectId
```

GET_ALL_RECORDS SP is used to retrieve all the records

Here I'm passing Project Id as a Parameter to fetch records for only that project Id.

I'm getting result like

```
    A         B         C            D

   value1   value2    value3       value4
```

Where A B C D are column names.

I want to get the value of D column. 
How can I modify the above query ( 
    `EXEC [dbo].[GET_ALL_RECORDS] @ProjectId` ) to get the column D value?

Which is the best way to retrieve that?

Comment: is there any chance to modify your procedure for returning output

Comment: I just want to pass the project Id. Yes we can modify the procedure.

Comment: project id is your input parameter.

Comment: Yes. It is the parameter

Comment: @DarkRob I have modified the way I've written. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If procedure is returning table type output then you must create a similar schema of that output table, you may create `#temp` table for that. 
Stores output of procedure in table then retrieve your data from `temp` table.

Example is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTable ([col1] NVARCHAR(100), [col2] NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO #TestTable
EXEC [dbo].[GET_ALL_RECORDS] @ProjectId   --- expecting @ProjectId is the variable in which you want to get the result
declare @output nvarchar(100)
set @output = (select top 1 col from #TestTable order by col )
```

Or if you can modify procedure then this will be your solution

```
  create proc myproc
  as 
  begin
      ----- do your code here
      declare @output nvarchar(100)
      set @output = (select top 1 col from #TestTable order by col )  ---- assuming #TestTable is the table you get as output.
      return @output 
  end
  go
  declare @op nvarchar(100)
  exec @op = myproc
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code of your stored procedure is compatible with UDF limitations, you should consider transforming it into a user defined function returning a table.
Thus you can use it in an expression like:

```
SELECT D FROM [dbo].[GET_ALL_RECORDS](@ProjectId)
```

while you will still be able to use all the fields whenever appropriate:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[GET_ALL_RECORDS](@ProjectId)
```